# Replace dynamically filled HTML element through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**Background:**

I'm trying create a button or link which enables the user to download a .json file. This file is dynamic and changes depending on what the user does (outside the scope of the question).

I've created a button, which when clicked, generates a blob and a link to download the .json file. However, when the data changes, a new link is created behind the current link, instead of replacing the current one.

[image]

**Question:**

How do I alter my code to just replace the existing link, instead of creating a double?

**JS code:**

```
function download_rapport(){
    var data = geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; });
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
    var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download    = "backup.json";
    a.href        = url;
    a.textContent = "Download backup.json";

    document.getElementById('content_test').appendChild(a);
};
```

I've tried innerHTML instead of appendChild, but instead of a link, it just returns the link as a string.

**HTML code:**

```
 <form action="javascript:submitQuery()" id="advancedSearch">  
<!-- Modal/Pop-up window -->
<div id="generateReport" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <button onclick="download_rapport()">Generate download</button> 
        <div id="content_test"></div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Fastfood report</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="table-responsive" id="test">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML where the download div is located, see `Generate download`

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: Edited question, see HTML code

Comment: I updated my answer with working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `content_test` is a `div` containing only the links, you can replace `appendChild(a)` with `innerHTML = a.outerHTML`

`appendChild` adds the content passed in the arguments each time it is called.

To replace the content you can use the property `innerHTML`.

`outerHTML` on a element returns the HTML code you need to insert in the div.

The last line should look like this:

```
document.getElementById('content_test').innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Mm, this might be the better way. Likely faster.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're appending instead of replacing it.

Try removing the last element first:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content_test');
if (content.length > 0) {
    content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
} 
content.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written `document.getElementById('content_test').appendChild(a)`;
-Which means it will always add at the end of 'content_test'.

To Replace entire content you need to use innerHTML. E.g.,

```
document.getElementById('content_test').innerHTML = a;
```

**InnerHTML** specifies the HTML content of an element

Comment: I already tried innerHTML, but it gives an error: `ReferenceError: download_rapport is not defined`

Comment: @JordiZ I don't think that error is possible with just this change.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Without HTML, we can't know how he made the page. Maybe `content_test` is a `div` containing the button AND links.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ How would that give him a reference error to the enclosing function though? And if it does contain the button as well, your guy's way will remove the button on click.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Maybe the JS code is contained in the `div` (not the button) and when a second click is made, the function is not found.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Do you mean the div might contain a `<script>` tag containing this function? That would be an exceptionally odd way to set it up, but yes, I guess that would cause this error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This is what I meant, but the posted HTML does not contain any `script` tag.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry my bad, added a ; by accident. When adding innerHTML, the link is removed. Instead `blob:http://localhost/c08b836e-3b81-485b-83d7-58cfa0072b62` appear in its place.